# How to solve elasticsearch index not found error on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I am trying to push my rails app on heroku, am using elastic-search in the app so on heroku i added the bonsai add on, everything works on Development, but on heroku it's giving the `Application error` when i checked the logs i found this:

```
Bonsai: Initializing default Elasticsearch client with https://rppeji3zrn:FILTERED@redwood-5622314.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net
2018-09-05T10:04:37.828500+00:00 app[web.1]: [!!!] Index does not exist (Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound)
2018-09-05T10:04:37.875396+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! Unable to load application: Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden: [403] {"code":403,"message":"Updates to this cluster have been disabled. Please contact support@bonsai.io for further details."}
2018-09-05T10:04:37.875554+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/puma)
2018-09-05T10:04:37.875661+00:00 app[web.1]: Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden: [403] {"code":403,"message":"Updates to this cluster have been disabled. Please contact support@bonsai.io for further details."}
```

I am pretty new to rails so am not getting what's causing the error, any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Can you try running this `heroku run rake environment tire:import CLASS=ModelName FORCE=true`

Comment: hey @KedarnagMukanahallipatna i tried that but it gives the error: Don't know how to build task 'tire:import'

Comment: Are you using any gem for `bonsai` like this?  `bonsai-elasticsearch-rails`
`

Comment: yes i am using that gem @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: Try `heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='ModelName'`